# Get attr when known class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is some code:
http://jsfiddle.net/T65E3/3/
I want to get an `attr` when i know `class`

```
$("#find").click(function() {
    $("#test").append($("#file").find("a.higlight").attr("rel"));
});
```

and html

```
 <div id="file">
<ul>
<li>
        <a class="higlight" rel="a">value_my</a>
        <a class="sth" rel="b">val</a>
        <a class="sth" rel="c">val2</a>
        <a class="sth" rel="d">val3</a>

</li>
</ul>
</div>

<button type="submit" id="find">find</button>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: jsFiddle is great for demonstrating your code, however, please post the code in your question as well.  (You also have Mootools loaded in your jsFiddle so the jQuery will not run.  Otherwise, your code is working.)

Comment: You forgot to load jQuery in your example, it works fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/T65E3/5/

Comment: Note that `$("#file").find("a.higlight").attr("rel")` will only give you the attribute from the 1st element.  You'd need to use `.each` or `.map` to get multiple elements' attributes.

Comment: Yes i know, i need one element only :) But in my code, shows as `undefined`.

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski: The code you posted works fine (as long as you include jQuery).

Comment: In your jsFiddle, look at the left pane under "Framework"... **change Mootools to jQuery**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as-is (if you include jQuery, your example had MooTools), works fine.  There's just one thing I'd like to point out.

```
$("#file").find("a.higlight").attr("rel") // 'a'
```

This will only return you the `rel` attribute of the first matched element.  To get all the `rel` attributes (if there were multiple elements), you can use `.map`.

```
$("#file").find("a.sth").attr("rel") // 'b'

$("#file").find("a.sth").map(function(){
    return this.rel;
}).get(); // ['b','c','d']
```

Comment: But when i'm alert it in my code it shows me "undeined"

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/T65E3/5/  Double check the class on the elements, make sure there is an element with the class `higlight`.

Comment: Hmm. I'm using my code in $dialog - jquery. In firebug html code is grey - which is "dialoging". Is it a reason?

Comment: @GabrielŻukowski: The code is grey because it is hidden (I think), which wouldn't matter here.  See if you can re-create your problem in jsFiddle (there's an option to load jQuery UI if you need it).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It looks like it can't find class. I try to figured how to fix this and I write.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the text() method instead of append for adding text into an element; but your main problem was you were calling MooTools onload instead of jQuery. If you change that, your script runs just fine.